# An exponential map of a matrix computation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras

Suppose the $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $M$ satisfy $AM+MA^{T}=0.$ Show by direct computation that the product $\mathrm{exp}(At)~M~\mathrm{exp}(A^{T}t)=M$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}.$

Note: By definition of exponential map to have $$LHS=(I+tA+\frac{t^2A^2}{2!}+\frac{t^3A^3}{3!}+\cdots)M(I+tA^{T}+\frac{t^2(A^{T})^2}{2!}+\frac{t^3(A^{T})^3}{3!}+\cdots)=(M+tAM+\frac{t^2A^2 M}{2}+\frac{t^3A^3M}{3!}+\cdots)(I+tA^{T}+\frac{t^2(A^{T})^2}{2!}+\frac{t^3(A^{T})^3}{3!}+\cdots)=M+B.$$ In which B consists of some chunks of matrices. How to efficently show by computation that $B =0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Differentiate with respect to $t$.

Comment: Upon differentiaing I obtain $exp(At)AMexp(A^{T}t)+exp(At)Mexp(A^{T}t)A^{T}$ which seems not vanishing. I perceive your aim is to show the derivative is zero and thus let $t=0$ to obtain the answer.

Comment: $A^T$ commutes with $e^{tA^T}$.

Comment: I see. So $A$ also commutes with $e^{At},$ which gives $Aexp(At)Mexp(A^{T}t)-Aexp(At)Mexp(A^{T}t)=0.$ Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need that.

Answer (score 1):

To proceed with direct calculation, first start with the relation $AM = -MA^T$ and show by induction that $A^n M = (-1)^n M(A^T)^n$ for all $n \ge 1$. With these identities at hand, we compute

\begin{align}\exp(At)M\exp(A^T t) &= \exp(At) \cdot \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{M(A^T)^m t^m}{m!} \\
&= \exp(At) \cdot \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m A^m M}{m!}t^m \\
&= \exp(At)\exp(-At)M\\
&= \exp(0t)M\\
&= M
\end{align}

Comment: Nice computation! But I can only accept one solution :(